# Show that $N(A^T A) \subset N(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that $N(A^T A) \subset N(A)$ where $A$ is a $p \times q$ real matrix and $N(A) = \lbrace x\in \mathbb R^q : A x = 0\rbrace$.

Here is my attempt. First I take $b \in N(A^T A)$. This implies that $b \in \mathbb R^q$ such that $A^TA b = 0$. I define $c = Ab$ and get that $A^T c = 0$. If $A$ was symmetric I would be set, but it isn't.

I feel like this is simple, but I just can't see where to go. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If $ A^T A b = 0,  $ then
$$ b^T A^T A b = 0,  $$ so
$$  (Ab)^T (Ab) = 0.  $$
What does that tell you about $Ab?$ If $v$ is any column vector, what is $v^T v?$

Comment: $Ab$ is orthogonal to itself which must mean that it equals zero. Is that right?